# Epicurus's claim that the mind is in the heart

Tags: reference-request, epicurus

I'm looking for a reference to back the claim made on SEP:

> The mind, which is located at the heart, is a center that controls the other soul-parts as well as the body, and that receives and processes information supplied by the subordinate parts.

I got this from:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ancient-soul/

If possible I would like an actual quote from some work of Epicurus to support this claim.  Thank you!

Comment: This was under the Stoic theory of the soul. I assume you would like Stoic references to this idea.

Comment: yes please......

Comment: A modern (ie post modern scientific anatomy) teacher who nevertheless insisted that the heart "on the right side!" is the seat of consciousness was Ramana https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/sri-ramana-maharshi-on-heart

Comment: I once read a report saying that a system of neurons has been found in the heart, giving it some of the physical properties of the brain, but I've never seen this mentioned elsewhere. I may go looking again. It's a common claim. It may be muddled a little in writings on consciousness by the use of the word 'heart' to mean 'core', 'essence', 'ground' and so forth and not always the physical heart.

Comment: @PeterJ Heart can mean 1 blood pump 2 what you call core essence etc roughly identifiable with Ramana's heart 3 solar plexus which would match your neuron definition 4 anahat chakra of yoga/tantra 5 possibly manipur chakra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind in the heart was a common Greek view, not specific to Epicurus, see [Why did ancient Greeks think of "heart as seat of soul"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/50089/why-did-ancient-greeks-think-of-heart-as-seat-of-soul) Epicurus's [works are not extant](https://www.iep.utm.edu/epicur/#H2), except for three letters on other topics included by Diogenes Laertius. So, alas, there are no direct quotes. But Lucretius's De Rerum Natura is considered a faithful exposition of Epicurean views, and he discusses soul's function and location at length in [Book 3, 3.190ff](http://johnstoniatexts.x10host.com/lucretius/lucretius3html.html):

> *Now, I claim mind and soul are held united
>
>   and together form a single nature,
>                          but the main one, which, as it were, has power
>
>   in the entire body, is our judgment,
>
>   which we call the mind or understanding,
>
>   fixed in place in the mid-part of the chest.
>                       For here throb fear and terror. Soothing joys
>
>   move round this region, too. And therefore here
>
>   are mind and understanding. Of the soul,
>
>   all other parts, dispersed through the whole body,
>
>   obey and are moved in accordance with
>                       the will and inclination of the mind.*

Comment: Epicurus always seems to me to be right about so many things. It would be a shame (for me) if this notion were directly attributable to him and not just a commonly held belief at the time. So I'll choose to believe this is apocraphal :)